# xrandr command does not work in lightdm.conf

Tags: x11, xrandr

my `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
display-setup-script=xrandr --newmode "2560x1440" 220.812 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1478 -hsync -vsync  && xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "2560x1440" && xrandr --output HDMI1 --rotate right
```

When I start the computer, there is a black blank screen as the x server is stopped due to an error. When I run the `xrandr` command normally in terminal when logged in, it does work.

Errors in  `~/.xsession-errors.old`

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: window-stack-bridge main process (2057) killed by HUP signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (2115) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (2186) killed by HUP signal
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (2188) killed by HUP signal
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2195) killed by HUP signal
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (2202) killed by HUP signal
upstart: indicator-messages main process (2231) killed by HUP signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (2232) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-power main process (2233) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (2234) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-keyboard main process (2235) killed by HUP signal
upstart: indicator-sound main process (2236) killed by HUP signal
upstart: indicator-printers main process (2239) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-session main process (2240) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-application main process (2249) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-application pre-stop process (3254) killed by HUP signal
upstart: unity7 main process (2277) terminated with status 1
```

Comment: Do you see a related error in ~/.xsession-errors?  I guess you should try a single script like `display-setup-script=/path/to/myscript.sh`.  So create such script with all needed commands. Don't forget shebang `#!/bin/sh` and execution permissions.

Comment: @rudimeier I tried that with the /path/to/script exactly as you write except with `#!/bin/bash`